# What is the purpose of a "-" prefix to the log file path in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf and similar files?

Tags: linux, performance, syslogd

Among others these lines appear in the file:

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*                       -/var/log/daemon.log
```

What is the purpose of the leading "-" in the path? It doesn't seem to be documented in the manpage and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` before output file name increases performance (reduces number of physical IO operations) by making logging less "crash resistant".  It makes sense in case of high volume less critical log entries.

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html

> **Actions**
>   The Action object describe what is to be done with a message. *[...]*
>   **Regular File**
>   Typically messages are logged to real files. *[...]* You may prefix each entry with the minus “-‘’ sign to omit syncing the file after **every** logging. Note that you might lose information if the system crashes right behind a write attempt. Nevertheless this might give you back some performance, especially if you run programs that use logging in a very verbose manner.